# Reverse Numbers function using recursion in C

Tags: c, function, recursion, reverse

The following is a function that is meant to return the reverse of a number using recursion.  However, it only returns the last digit of the number.  I'd like to know why and how to fix it?

```
int rev(int number)
{
      int revNum=0, sum=100;

      if(number<=9) return(number);
      else if(number>0) 
      {
           return(rev(number/10)+revNum);
           revNum=(number%10)*sum; sum=sum/10;

      }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: what do you mean reverse the number? as for the code, everything after that return statement has no meaning

Comment: `if(number<=9)` else `if(number>0)` what is that??There is something between 0-9 which is ready to satisfy both condition.

Comment: he wants to reverse the digits, so: 1234 becomes 4321

Comment: BTW: the last line `revNum=(number%10)...` will be never reached

Comment: the problem is mostly because `sum` is not preserved across recursion, among other things

Comment: @MyPasswordIsLasercats if I move the return statement below the last line, will it work

Comment: You are not returning the value properly in all iterations. Thats y the prob arise. You can check my recurssion solution below.

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva you can check my answer too. it's 1 line of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's some working code:

```
int rev (int number){
    int base = 1;

    while (number / (base * 10)){/*
        * This calculates the base of the number
        * ie number = 435
        *    base   = 100
        */
        base *= 10;
    }

    if (number <= 9){
        return number;
    } else if (number >= 10){ // notice different expression
        int revNum = (number % 10) * base; // this was out of order
        return rev (number / 10) + revNum;
    }
}
```

The main reason your code couldn't work, other than what I commented above, is that `sum` isn't preserved within the calls. This is a common problem in making recursive functions.

To remedy this, the "base" is calculated each function call, instead of having a fixed value. This also a bit better because it allows larger numbers to be passed, instead of ones not bigger than `100` (another limit of the code you've chosen).

Another implementation is to base the base as a second parameter, so that it doesn't have to be recalculated every function call. This can, however, be easily remedied by a simple macro. The call may be :

```
int rev_number (int number, int base){ .. }
```

But a can be conveniently placed in a macro (or other function call):

```
#define rev(num) rev_number (number, 0)
```

This is a little more efficient, but the difference may or may not be important.

Comment: @Jost it's more contained but less efficient, since the base is calculated every call.

Comment: @Taylor_Flores Yeah, but to be honest - we are dealing with recursive functions - the function calls are expensive (and multiple parameters don't make it better ;-) ). I think it is only for learning purposes: transform a function into a recursive function or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution is crystal clear; except I don't understand what while(number/(base*10)) does?

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva The value of `number/base*10` should be 1 for the loop to execute

Comment: The while loop could be moved into the else if statement to make things slightly quicker when number is 0-9. In other words, there isn't much point of attempting to calculate a base when the number is 0-9.

Answer (score 9):

This is the solution.

Call below function as `reverse (number, 0);`

```
int reverse(long int n, long int rev) {
    if(n == 0)
        return rev; 
    return reverse(n / 10, rev * 10 + n % 10);
}
```

Comment: One `int` divide by 10 and one `int ` multiply by 10 per number of digits: most efficient.

Answer (score 7):

```
int rev(int num){
    return num < 10 ? num : (num % 10) * pow(10, (int)log10(num)) + rev(num/10);
}
```

And it's done in one line.

Comment: wow it works, although I'm not sure how you utilized pow and log to make it work?

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva well `(num % 10)` is last digit so in order it to be first you have to multiply it with a value which starts with an 1, continues with 0 and has exactly as many digits as your `num`. So basicly if your number is `123456` , `(num % 10) * pow(10, (int)log10(num))` computes first time `600000' then '50000' and so on. An when the last value which is less then `10` is returned it starts adding the results.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie why does being in one line make it better? a) it's less readable. b) it's not even recursive

Comment: @TaylorFlores a) the program will occupy less hard disc memory and will use less operating memory b) it is recursion since i'm calling `rev(num/10)` over and over again.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie actually those are good points. And I just now saw the call at the end of the line (my bad), I guess I can't argue that this isn't a better solution, + 1

Comment: @TaylorFlores you know... I checked both of them and in terms of speed, your is a little faster then mine. Approximately 1.25 times. I think it is because of `pow` and `log10` being computed slowly. So in my case it is just saving the hard memory.

Comment: Should one attempt this approach with `long long`  (63 vs 53, any integer bit width wider that `double` fraction), the rounding incurred with the `integer_type` to `double` with `log10(num)` will corrupt the answer.

Comment: @chux `rev(0)` - `return num < 10 ? num : ...` so 0 will be returned straight away.
Would casting to `long long` solve the 2nd problem as well?

Comment: True about `rev(0)` returns 0 right away.  2nd becomes a becomes a `long long`.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi A small correction Your code returns the first digit(not last digit) of the entered number.**Here is the reason

You are calculating revNum after returning some value like this

```
    return(rev(number/10)+revNum);
    revNum=(number%10)*sum; sum=sum/10;
```

hence the second statement has no effect.

Also **revNum** is a local variable

So every time when you are calling a recursive function new local copies of **sum**(local variable) and revNum are getting created and initialized with 0 and 100 respectively.

Your recursive tree looks like this,For example **596** is the number passed to the recursive function.

```
              rev(596) //call from main
              rev(59)-->rev(5) // these are recursive calles
```

Now rev(5) returns 5(since 5 < 9) back to the caller i.e to rev(59) from there to the caller which is in main, resulting the display of the first digit, in this case it is 5.

**How to fix it?**

To fix that issue, you have to make them global variables(sum and revNum) also return statement should be at the end, after calculating the reverse number. Here is the simple code.

I made **reverse** variable as global to preserve the changes in it, finally I'm returning the same to the caller.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int reverse;           //globally declared
    int rev(int revNum)
    {
       if(revNum)
       {
          reverse = (reverse * 10) + (revNum % 10);
          rev(revNum/10);    //recursive call 
       }
       else              
        return;    //return back to caller when revNum becoms 0
    return reverse;          
    }

   int main()
   {
       int num;
       printf("Enter a number:");
       scanf("%d",&num);
       printf("Reverse Number is:%d\n",rev(num));
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: This does work, but I am not sure what value reverse holds as its value is not declared; so (reverse*10) would translate into what?

Comment: Hi Michael, as it is a global variable, it will get initialized to zero,hence at first time reverse*10 will become zero.

Comment: Fails `rev(0)` as return value not provided.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple beginner question so I think we need to write a simple code to answer it too.
In this way we don't need to create new variables.

`n%10` gives us the last number,first we print 
the last one and then we call reverse function gain but now with parameter `n/10` so we get rid of last number which is already printed.

***Code***

```
int reverse(int n)
{
        if(n<10)
            printf("%d",n);
        else
        {
            printf("%d",n%10); 
            reverse(n/10);
        }
}
```

Comment: Works well for all `n >=  0` with incurring `int` overflow as others.

Comment: Suggested simplification: `void reverse(int n) { 
        printf("%d",n%10); 
        if (n >= 10) reverse(n/10);
    }`
}

Answer (score 1):

May be this snippet helps:

```
//init reversed number with last digit of number
reversed_number=number % 10;
//remove the last digit of number
number=number / 10;

//if number has another digit...
while (number > 0)
{
    //...shift left all digits of the reversed_number by one digit
    //    and add the last digit of number
    reversed_number=reversed_number*10+(number % 10);
    //remove the last digit of number
    number=number / 10;
}
```

---

...added later...

The recursive variant looks like this (I used two functions to have the desired signature):

```
int rev(int number)
{
    return rev_ext(0,number);
}

int rev_ext(int result, int number)
{
    if (number<10)
    {
        return result*10+number;
    }
    else
    {
        result=result*10 + number % 10;
        return rev_ext(result, number / 10);
    }
}
```

I'm sure it can be written shorter/optimized ;-)

*Jost

Comment: @Taylor - yes you are right, but counting the number of digits of the input is somehow "text processing" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursive solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   int pow(int a, int b){
        int p = 1;
        while(b){
            p = p * a;
            b--;
        }
        return p;
    }

    int len(int number) {
        int i = 0;
        while (number) {
            number/=10;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    int rev(int number) {
        int revNum=0;
        int i = len(number) - 1;

        if(number<=9) {
            return number;
        } else {
            return(number%(10)*pow(10,i) +rev(number/10));
        }
    }
    printf("%d",rev(1234));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this recursion version.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include<math.h>
int main()                                                  
{
  int n=345;
  printf("%d",rev(n));
}
int len(int number) 
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;number>0;number=number/10,i++);
  return i;
}
int rev(int n)
{
   if (n==0) return 0;
   int val=0;
   val=n%10;
   return (val * pow(10,len(n)-1)+rev(n/10));
}
```